# Getting all the filtered data from a non-ajaxified datatable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, datatable, datatables

I've used datatables to list all users in my application. I've to add an ability for admin to perform "Delete" operation on filtered data in datatable. For example, typing "R" in search box of datatable lists all the possible data which conains letter "R". Now on clicking a button "Delete" would delete all those users. I've implemented this logic but it only takes data from the first page:

```
 $("#delete-users").click(function(){
        var status = confirm("All the users currently showing in the table will be deleted. Do you want to continue?");
        if(status){
            var users = new Array();
            $("table#users tbody tr").each(function() {
                users.push(this.id);
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/users/delete_selected",
                data: {
                    users: users
                }
            })
            .always(function() {
                window.location.reload();
            });
        }
    });
```

But I want to delete every data in the filtered set. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: which version of datatables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using dataTables v1.9 or better : You can retrieve all filtered rows this way (see the link below) :

```js
var filteredRows = dataTable._('tr', {"filter":"applied"});
```

Your function should look like this :

```js
$("#delete-users").click(function(){
    var status = confirm("All the users currently showing in the table will be deleted. Do you want to continue?");
    if(status){
        var users = []; 
        var filteredRows = dataTable._('tr', {"filter":"applied"});
        filteredRows.forEach(function(row) {
            //push value for the column index that holds id for the user
            //0 is just a demonstration
            users.push(row[0]);
        });
        //
        //...
        //
    }
});
```

here is a demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/73DEd/**

If you are using a dataTables version  below 1.9, you must use a plugin, see http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/214/how-to-get-searched-or-filtered-data/p1